# Convert a string value to Integer array

Tags: c#, arrays

I have class

```
public class Myclas
{
    public string EmpName{ get; set; }
    public string myStingId{ get; set; }      
}
```

I would like to convert this string (myStingId)to an int array.

```
int[] listOfMyValues = null;

listOfMyValue s=  Int32.Parse(myStingId,CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToArray();
```

i have tried the above and recieve an error int doesnt contain a definition for array.

Comment: Your question is unclear

Comment: can you please provide us input and expected output. What is in the myStringId?

Comment: Can you add some exemple of myStingId. If myStingId = "1,2,3"; an solution will be myStingId.Split(",").Select(num => Int32.Parse(num,CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)).ToArray();

Answer (score 1):

May be my solution is over engineered, but here is the alternate way

```
string myStingId = "6299857"
int[] result = Array.ConvertAll(myStingId.ToCharArray(), 
         x => int.Parse(x.ToString(), , CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
```

Output:

```
[6, 2, 9, 9, 8, 5, 7]
```

[Try Online](https://dotnetfiddle.net/GiowKY)